# How to increment an int every time I run my tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm testing my methods of one database but I have a problem with my Insert test because my object has an autoincrement ID which is created by default when insert the object BUT also it has a name which has to be unique, so the first time I run my test it works perfectly but no more. I though about put an int i = 0 and then increment it and interpolate it into my string but it is reset every time I run my test so it doesn't work. Any ideas?

This is my test:

```
public async Task CanCreateStringSignal()
{
    var s = new SignalsDTO()
    {
        Name = "Signal",
        TagType = "String",
        Description = "Foo"
    };
    
    var idReturn = await _handler.Create(s);
    var signal = await _handler.GetSignalsByName("Signal");

    Assert.IsNotNull(signal);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(signal, typeof(SignalsDTO));
    Assert.AreEqual("Signal", signal.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(idReturn, signal.IDTag);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you clean the database between test runs ? Aren't you concerned of contamination between tests (a little like you're observing in this case) ?

Comment: Minor, but why do you mix non-blocking and blocking async calls?

Comment: @sidewinder94 I don't have access to the sql, maybe I could use dapper to query a drop?

Comment: @peter-csala true, I was fighting with my names problem and I didn¡t saw that. Thank you

Comment: Integration tests that interact with a database should be responsible for bringing up a pristine local copy of the database loaded with appropriate test data for each test. Good testing requires *consistent results* and you will never achieve that with a single mutable data source that is persisted between tests and test runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append some GUID and you'll be fine:

```
Name = "Signal" + Guid.NewGuid()
```

Now, on each run, now and in 100 years, the name will be unique.